# Bootstrap - auto-dropdown navigation menus in collapsed mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In a bootstrap navigation bar, I have a dropdown menu.

On smaller screen, the navigationbar is collapsed, and I get a button to toggle the visibility of the navigation bar items.

Since the only item that I have, is the dropdown menu, I feel it a little 'stupid' to have to first click to toggle the navigation visibility, and then click to drop down the menu.

I can see that what actually triggers the dropdown is the adding of class `open` to the dropdown menu - just like `in` seems to triggers the visibility of the collapsed navigation bar.

But how can I make the dropdown 'auto-dropdown' when the collapsed navigation bar is displayed?

A small fiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/2eyvryck/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
        height:auto ! important;
        display:block ! important;
        visibility: visible ! important;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2eyvryck/1/

Comment: I have probably not expressed my self clear enough. Your code will always display the dropdown menu-link, but not the dropdown menu itself. I want the dropdown menu-items - the nested `<li>` items to be visible.

Comment: Now we're talking :-) At least if we remove the selector from your first answer. Cause that one makes the complete menu visible all the time.
But... I wished there was another solution, though. Cause clicking the dropdown menuitem still toggles the 'open'-class, which makes it important that everything renders the same, whether it has the open class or not. I would prefer a solution that automatically ads the 'open'-class when the first collapse-button is pressed, or when the screen gets narrow or something, but what ever works :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JQuery version. It doesn't look great, but does keep the toggle function.

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){$('.dropdown-toggle').parent().addClass('open');},300)
});
```

Need `setTimeout` so it fires after Bootstrap closes the dropdown when the nav menu opens.

Comment: Wow. I never considered this option. Since the navbar-toggle will only be toggled on small screens, this can work. Thanks!